# Akka application in Tomcat7 not sending response

Tags: tomcat, get, akka

I have an akka application developed in Servlet 3 deployed in Tomcat 7. Inside the app, the servlet has a doGet method. doGet is served on asynchronous context. If the doGet does not get a required input in a period of 12 mts, the request sends back a response of idle time out. The issue is I am not getting this response back which I am setting in application. I am not seeing any exceptions in the log. When I set the timeout value to 5 mts, I am getting the response. Could any one help?

Comment: Can you clarify what happens in your application once doGet is called? From your description it is difficult to tell how the interaction with Akka works.

Comment: Inside doGet, its waiting for a trigger from an external server. If it does not get the response, the request will time out.

Comment: Check the client timeout. Chances are your client is giving up because the server is taking too long to send the response.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for 5 min but not for 12 then I would say the client or some other dependent process is giving up before the expected time can elapse. I would check all the other timeouts related to client, Tomcat and so on.